# Postgresql extension pageinspect - mean bt_metap

Tags: postgresql, dbms, btree, postgresql-extensions

I am using Postgresql extension pageinspect.

Could someone tell me the meaning of these columns: magic, version, root, level, fastroot, fastlevel of the bt_metap function.

This information is not presents in the documentation [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pageinspect.html)[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pageinspect.html]

The height of the b-tree (position of node farthest from root to leaf), is the column Level?

See below a return query that I ran on an index called idx_l_shipmodelineitem000

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
postgres # SELECT * FROM bt_metap ('idx_l_shipmodelineitem000');
postgres # magic    | version   | root     | level | fastroot | fastlevel
postgres # 340322   | 2         | 41827 | 3       | 41827   | 3
```

Best regards

Comment: No idea why you did get a downvote, but this is an excellent question. Answer for that question seems to be a bit hard to find on the manual page. In such cases I tend to read the PostgreSQL source code ...

Answer (score 1):

`src/include/access/nbtree.h`:

```
/*
 * The Meta page is always the first page in the btree index.
 * Its primary purpose is to point to the location of the btree root page.
 * We also point to the "fast" root, which is the current effective root;
 * see README for discussion.
 */

typedef struct BTMetaPageData
{
    uint32      btm_magic;      /* should contain BTREE_MAGIC */
    uint32      btm_version;    /* should contain BTREE_VERSION */
    BlockNumber btm_root;       /* current root location */
    uint32      btm_level;      /* tree level of the root page */
    BlockNumber btm_fastroot;   /* current "fast" root location */
    uint32      btm_fastlevel;  /* tree level of the "fast" root page */
} BTMetaPageData;
```

So I suggest reading [src/backend/access/nbtree/README](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/nbtree/README;hb=HEAD)